# Getting "removeattr is not a function" exception

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery-1.7.2.min.js

I'm getting TypeError:

```
$("#TextBox1").removeattr is not a function [Break On This Error]   
$("#TextBox1").removeattr("disabled");
```

Why?

Comment: JS is caseSensitive Bro. right `removeAttr()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct function name is [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/), not `removeattr`:

```
$("#TextBox1").removeAttr("disabled");
```

But starting from jQuery 1.6 it's better to use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method for setting native attributes such as `disabled` and `checked`:

```
$('#TextBox1').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: TIP : if we use `.prop()` then `.removeProp()` will do the same as `removeAttr()`

Comment: @diEcho, no, not at all. I am quoting you the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) of the `removeProp` method: `Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#TextBox1").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct function name is `removeAttr()`, not `removeattr()`:

```
$("#TextBox1").removeAttr("disabled");
```

It is camelCase.